# Ubuntu network interfaces file has only lo and not getting updated even after adding eth0.How to overcome this in VMware 16 pro?

Tags: networking, vmware, interface

[Output of ifconfig -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmXhJ.jpg)

[Contents of /etc/network/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYNrv.png)

I was trying to assign a static ip for my Virtual machine but couldn't succeed in pinging it from my windows machine. I also tried all the solutions available.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

These are the contents of interfaces file:

```
interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo eth0

iface lo inet loopback 

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.11.10
network 192.168.11.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.11.1
```

These are the output of ifconfig -a :

```
shakthivel@ubuntu:/etc/network$ ifconfig -a

ens33: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0c:29:5c:14:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens36: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0c:29:5c:14:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7490  bytes 534296 (534.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7490  bytes 534296 (534.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In VMware Virtual network Editor

```
Subnet IP : 192.168.11.0 

Type:NAT 

DHCP:Disabled
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, it matters.

Comment: Also please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question. Pictures are often cut off, can not be searched and require you leave the question to see them.

Comment: Please check I have edited my question

Comment: You have no interface named eth0. The system won't bring up a non-existent interface. The /etc/network/interfaces process is deprecated in Ubuntu 17.10 and later in favor of netplan. Please see: `man netplan` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it seems there is no netplan package in my ubuntu. `Command 'netplan' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install netplan.io ` But I can't install anything as I am not connected to internet :(